# Is it bad practice to select an entire slice in redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I want to select an entire slice in redux like the following:

```
interface AuthState {
  user?: User;
  shouldShowLogin: boolean;
}

export const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'auth',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setUser: ...,
    showLogin: ...,
    hideLogin: ...,
  },
});

export const useAuth = () => useSelector((state) => state.auth);
```

So I could do something like `const { user, shouldShowLogin } = useAuth();` within components. This is handier in most cases but I'm not sure if it's bad practice/inefficient.

I want to do something similar for dispatch (i.e. abstract away useDispatch()). Maybe something like `const setUserWithDispatch = (info) => useDispatch()(info);` so I can do simply `setUserWithDispatch(userInfo)` in my components, without having to do `useDispatch()` and then `dispatch(setUser(userInfo))`.

Ideally, I'd like to do `const { user, shouldShowLogin, setUser, showLogin, hideLogin } = useAuth();` but I'm not sure how to go about it. Again, is this bad practice/inefficient? Why doesn't redux configure this automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The component will rerender when the value selected from `useSelector` changes.  Consequently, you generally want to select the minimum amount of information that you need in order to minimize rerenders.

If there are multiple properties in `state.auth` and you only care about one then the downside to this destructuring approach is that it will cause the component to rerender when other properties of the object change.  In your example you seem to be using all of the properties so it shouldn’t matter.

I think you will have a hard time doing something custom with `dispatch` without violating the [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).  Hooks cannot be called conditionally and must be called at the top level of the component.  You cannot call `useDispatch` (or a custom hook that uses it) inside of an event handler callback, inside a `useEffect` function, etc.

The current implementation of the `useDispatch` hook means that you call `useDispatch` once per component to get access to the `dispatch` function for the current store based on the react-redux context.  The returned `dispatch` function is a pure function (not a hook) and can be used anywhere.

You could use redux’s [`bindActionCreators`](https://redux.js.org/api/bindactioncreators) to bind actions to the dispatch for a particular store instance.  This sounds like what you are trying to do, but it is advised against. The downside is that you create an unnecessary coupling between the actions and a particular store instance. You would lose the ability to use a different store instance for testing.